# Installing gcc without repo's or yum

Tags: centos, gcc, repository, internet

I am having issues installing gcc with Yum. I can't contact repos, and can't install developer tools either.

Is there some sort of link I can wget and install at `.tgz` file?

Here is my issue:

```
[root@localhost]# yum -y install gcc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                     | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                     |  15 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                   | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                  | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
xymon                                                                    | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
xymon-testing                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * updates: repo.us.bigstepcloud.com
```

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: Seems like a better solution would be to check your network connectivity, and if that's good, check your repo list

Answer (score 3):

You can install this with [**yum**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html) using **localinstall**:

> localinstall is used to install a set of local rpm files. If required
>   the
>                 enabled repositories will be used to resolve dependencies.
>                 Note that the install command will do a local install, if
>                 given a filename. This command is maintained for legacy
>                 reasons only.

Download the rpm from a repository, don't forget to chose the right OS version (ex: [CentOS repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/)) and then run the following command:

`yum localinstall /path/to/the/package.rpm`

---

*Additional info:* it's more interesting to install rpm with `yum` then with `rpm` command. This way, installed package will be listed in yum database.